# How to remap control-c to control-shift-c in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2

I have tried a few things. I can't do the karabiner control to command because that breaks my workspace changing keys.

I just want control-shift-c to kill/end (like control-c does) and have control-c copy.

Telling control-c to be copy selected from menu does not seem to work.

Comment: you can customize karabiner so that a keybinding only occurs when certain programs are active. or so that it isn't enabled when a certain program is active. See "type" : "frontmost_application_unless" in karabiner.json, or :applications in Goku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no control-shift-c in the ASCII character set.  control-c is all that's available.  Another way of saying it is that they map to the same character in the ASCII character set.

Comment: This is correct, however, not the correct answer to the question

Answer (score 5):

Are you on a Mac? You can do it as follows in iTerm3:

Go iTerm -> Preferences.

Click on the Keys tab, then click the `+` in the bottom right next to `Load Preset...`

Settings:
Keyboard shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
Action: Select menu item
Last option: Copy

[image]

Comment: Worked as a charm! The caveat was the `Select Menu item...` instead of base `Copy` option as some might expect. Thank you!